# No delegate method in MainViewController.webView

Tags: ios, cordova

I created a new Cordova app and I want to add in *MainViewController.m* the line

```
self.webView.delegate = self;
```

But the compiler says there is no `delegate` method in `self.webView`.

I also wanted to add in *AppDelegate.m*:

```
[self.viewController.webView loadRequest:myRequest]
```

But there is no `loadRequest` method either.

I see those lines in a working old cordova app I have. Did something changed? How am I supposed to write these lines now?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

I can do `[self.viewController.webViewEngine loadRequest:myRequest]` and it works, but can't do `self.webViewEngine.delegate = self`.
What is this webViewEngine? Does anyone can deduce something from this?

Comment: have you implemented/confirmed the protocol for web view?

Comment: I'm very new to cordova and iOS development generally. Can you please expand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12451:

> This is not a bug, those changes were made to allow "plugable webviews" as plugins, were you can use any engine (on iOS UIWebView or WKWebView), so now there is some abstraction on how to get the webview as it can have a different class depending on the engine you set.
>   If you haven't installed the WKWebView engine plugin, then you are using UIWebView, when you access self.webview, it's a UIView now because of the abstraction, but you can cast it to UIWebView and use it as you did before.

So all I needed to do was to cast the `webView` to `UIWebView` and it had all the methods.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have written is for `UIWebview` but judging from the compiler's response of the delegate not being present, the webview you are probably using is `WKWebview`

In that case the code should be:

```
self.webview.navigationDelegate = self;
[self.webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com"]]];
```

Comment: I don't have `navigationDelegate` either. Also, MainViewController inherits from CDVViewController and the webView comes from there. I'm pretty sure it's a UIWebView. I only see it's of type UIView